# .NET Windows service working only with debug binaries

Tags: .net, service

I have installed a Windows service developed in c#. The service has been installed by an msi package created by a visual studio installer project. When the service is installed with binaries coming from a release  build it fails to start and the service console returns the following error message:"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion". When the service is installed with debug binaries everything works as expected. I have added logs for every exception that occurs in the service's constructor, in the OnStart method, in the main method, and in the DoWork method of the main working thread of the service. The OnStart method of the service exits almost immediatly as it just initializes some variables from the configuration file and then starts the main working thread. I get no exception logged on the event viewer. I am clueless, how could I debug what is happening with the release binaries?
Thanks.

Comment: Rebuild the service and installation package in .NET. uninstall the already installed service . and then re install your service again. I have been experiencing same problem in past. above mentioned steps usually solve the problem. you may be required to reset the system too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove MSI from the process so as to better identify the root cause.

1. Compile your project in Release build.
2. Use InstallUtil to install the Release build binary as a Windows service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.80).aspx

Try to start this service and see if the same error message occurs.

It the service still fails to start, try to follow KB to set up service debugging,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344

As this is a .NET Windows service, you might learn about WinDbg and SOS,

http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2009/01/Learning-WinDBGSOS-and-Advanced-Debugging

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code to enable the service to run from a standalone console test harness. After all a service is just a fancy way managing start shut down and pause/resume. Then debug your code out side of being a service.

If that fails, then break the code into multiple assemblies and see if you can isolate the code module more precisely. Then try recreate the issue by logging the entry conditions to the  affected module, and recreating them in a console test harness

Edit: 
Just to chime in. 99% of services issues in complex enterprise service  code I've debugged has been solved using this pattern. The rest where security issues which @LexLi is right can't *always* solved by running the app as a console application.

Also my answer to all debugging issues is generally in this pattern:

1. Iteratively reduce systems (environment) complexity
2. Iteratively remove code (under test) complexity
3. Repeat until the problem be reproduced and then apply either source code or runtime debuggers, either custom or off the self.

Comment: A console running under current user account is not an effective to locate issues of a service that runs under service accounts such as Local System.

Comment: Agree with Li. In fact it runs fine as a console application. This was one of the first try i did. I would downvote this answer if only I had the necessary score.

Comment: @register You didn't mention that you did try. It might not be a good answer, but it's a good advice, imho. If running in console mode failed, you could debug. If it doesn't, chances are there is a file right problem.